# How to get the previous bazel build logs in a decent Way?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp, bazel-aspect

Is there a better way of Command line option to get the last bazel build output log in a decent way?

I am trying this first time. I found nothing here as well https://bazel.build/external/extension
https://bazel.build/configure/attributes

Any idea how we can print the output result in a good way for further processing.

Comment: Maybe the build event protocol is what you are looking for -> https://bazel.build/remote/bep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
ln -s $(bazel info output_base)/command.log ./
```